# How to measure the distance to a person from a standing camera in Javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, math, camera, object-detection

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to capture an image of a person standing (with known height and 90° camera angle) and calculate the distance to that person.

I've setup a basic browser app that can take pictures OR video and calculate the camera angle. But I'm stuck on the distance part.

- https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ramanujan-3srgxx?file=/src/App.js

[image]

I've read somewhere that "[Intercept Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)" and/or [openCV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv) might be used, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Anyone who knows or has built something similar that can;

- Find a good solution
- Has suggestions that the person could do to make measuring easier (standing on a line drawn on the camera for example)

[image]

Comment: This is also helpful; https://stonekick.com/blog/using-basic-trigonometry-to-measure-distance.html

Comment: A simple approximation is to try to calculate the angle theta from head to toe as a proportion of the known field angle, then if you know the camera height is H/2 where H is the person's height, it's simple trigonometry tan(theta/2) = H / (2x). If the camera height is not H/2 then the distance to the head will be different from the distance to the toes.